# bash script with with 2 user input variables not working

Tags: bash, mkv

I am using a bash script to remove audio and subtitle tracks from `.mkv` files with **mkvmerge**.

Until now, I manually changed the bash script depending on the tracks I wanted to keep.

As this is kinda stupid, I wanted to include user input into the script, which specifies these tracks as well as the file name suffix.

If I only use 1 user input variable for choosing the subtitle track, it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Which subtitle track would you like to keep?
read subsvar
for file in *mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}".lesssubs.mkv -s $subsvar "$file"
done
```

But if I try the same with 3 variables, none of them are used and all audio and subtitle tracks are excluded:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Audio track to keep: ' subvar
read -p 'Subtitle track to keep: ' audiovar
read -p 'Filename suffix: ' suffixvar

for file in *mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}".$suffixvar.mkv -a $audiovar -s $subvar "$file"
done
```

Comment: Add the `-r` flag to `read` and enclose your variables in double quotes, aslo try to debug, add `set -x` after the shebang to see the output.

Comment: Your bash script and how you use the variables you read is fine, it is how you use mkvmerge  that is the problem. So change your question to explain what you want to do with mkvmerge and explain what you have tried.

Comment: The mkvmerge command works perfectly fine if I don't use variables but write down the audio track and subtitle track directly into the script. For example:
```
for file in *mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}".changed.mkv -a 1 -s 4 "$file"
done 
```
The moment I try to handle that with user input variables, it stops working.

Comment: @PimPolacko replace "mkvmerge" with "echo mkvmerge" and try to do the examples manually. Copy the output, and try it for yourself.

Comment: @Gowiser, I did not say such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gowiser
Thank you very much, the "echo mkvmerge" helped a lot, as I didn't see the very obvious problem without it.
I screwed up the variable order (subvar <-> audiovar), which resulted in mkvmerge failing. The correct script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Audio track to keep: ' audiovar
read -p 'Subtitle track to keep: ' subvar
read -p 'Filename suffix: ' suffixvar

for file in *mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}"."$suffixvar".mkv -a "$audiovar" -s "$subvar" "$file"
done
```

Thanks again for the quick replies!